# How do I remove a query string from the URL in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url

I just launched a site in Wordpress. There is a query string at the end of the URL when the site is loaded. When developing it, I was using the Jetpack plugin, but I have since removed it and deleted it. I am not using a Cache plugin, and I am **not** looking to remove the query string from static resources only.

I need to remove it from the actual URL. Any ideas? I've Googled this to death and can't find anything.

Is the fact that I was using Jetpack causing this problem? If so, what can I do to get rid of the Jetpack settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be because you have 'geolocate with cache support' checked in woocommerce settings.

If you set it to Geolocate the querystring will go away.